# NameError: name 'password' is not defined in Kivy

Tags: python, authentication, kivy, kivy-language, nameerror

I am building a login page using Kivy and it always says that I have a name error and password is not defined. I found some tutorials but they look the same as mine so I cant figure out the problem. Hope someone can help.Thank you

Here is my code:

```
FloatLayout:
    TextInput:
        id: "password"
        name: "password"
        multiline: False
        hint_text: 'Enter Password'
        hint_text_color: (1,1,1,.5)
        pos_hint: {'center_y': .45, 'center_x':.5}
        size_hint: .3,.1
        on_text: 
            self.foreground_color: (1,0,0,1)
        foreground_color: (1,1,1,1) 
        background_color: (.14,.15,.30,.5)
        cursor_color: (1,1,1,1)
    Button:
        text:"Submit"
        pos_hint: {'center_y': .3, 'center_x':.5}
        size_hint: .1,.1
        on_release: 
            app.root.current = "dashboard" if password.text == "admin" else "login"
            root.manager.transition.direction = "left"
```

Comment: please share stack trace

Answer (score 0):

I think the error is because you but password as a string, not a variable maybe try `id: password`
And do you have the class dashboard? If not how do you switch to dashboard. This is how I learn to do it https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xaYn4XdieCs.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is because of your `id` is `"password"`. As clearly stated in kivy docs you shouldn't provide your id as a string. So, what you have to do is instead of `id: "password"` write `id: password`. Then it will work just fine.

Comment: If you found my answer helpful, then you might consider to [accept it](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers), so other people see it too :)